# Regex (PCRE) Match words between words

Tags: regex, pcre

Hi! I have a problem with correct PCRE expression. Need cath bolder words (animal's names) in sample text:

this animal is called **Hippo** and can overcome no more than
is called **Hippo** and can overcome no more than
**Hippo** and can overcome no more than
**Hippo** can overcome no more than
this animal is called **Grey Rabbit** and can overcome no more than
this animal is called **Small Grey Rabbit** can overcome no more than
This is a test. Animal is called **Small Grey Rabbit** can overcome no more than

Here is the expression was i made. Unfortunately i cannot made it work correct, pls help. {1,3} quantifier if it possible need replace with * (Matches 0 or more of the preceding token.)

```
(^|called )\K([a-z]* ?){1,3}(?=( and)? can overcome)
```

Comment: Try `(?:^|called\s+)\K[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*?(?=(?:\s+and)?\s+can\s+overcome)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8GIq3o/1).

Comment: OMG this is a beautiful! I Will try to study your expression. Thank You!

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
(?:^|called\s+)\K[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*?(?=(?:\s+and)?\s+can\s+overcome)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8GIq3o/1). *Details*:

- `(?:^|called\s+)` - start of string or `called` and one or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an upper letter and zero or more lowercase letters
- `(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]*)*?` - zero or more but as few as possible occurrences of one or more whitespaces, an upper and then zero or more lowercase letters
- `(?=(?:\s+and)?\s+can\s+overcome)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with

  - `(?:\s+and)?` - an optional occurrence of  zero or more whitespaces and `and`
  - `\s+can\s+overcome` - zero or more whitespaces, `can`,  zero or more whitespaces, `overcome`.